# Mongoose update without callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a typical schema and model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
    profile: {
        name: String,
        surname: String,
        photo: String
    },
    stats: {
        lastLogin: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        loginCount: Number,
        lastIP: String
    },
    source: String,
    deleted: Boolean,
    dateCreated: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

When I perform this update, it only works if I define the callback, else it simply executes but no value is changed in the database:

```
User.update({email:'foo@bar.com'}, {$inc: {'stats.loginCount': 1}});
```

This works:

```
User.update({email:'foo@bar.com'}, {$inc: {'stats.loginCount': 1}}, function() {});
```

Is this a bug? I don't see in the documentation if the callback is required but it's strange to require this… I think i'm missing something here.

Notes: I'm matching by email for testing proposes, I'm using mongoose v3.5.4 in NodeJS v0.8.17 with a simple Express v3.0.6 setup.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The right way to call `update` with mongoose is the following:

```
User.update(query, update).exec(callback);
```

This way you will be able to skip `callback`:

```
User.update(query, update).exec();
```

When you calls

```
User.update(query, update)
```

it returns a [query object](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js).

It's very useful when you querying your database, because you can manipulate with query object before executing it. For example, you can specify a [`limit`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit) for your `find` query:

```
User.find(query).limit(12).exec(callback);
```

`Update` uses the same mechanism, though its not so useful there.

Comment: You're totally right, I see now a note in the documentation of Mongoose about this (http://gan.so/diUO). I was so blind yesterday, thanks for pointing me.

Comment: Although it's confusing that if you provide a callback the query is executed instantly instead of returning a query object. I think they need to change this or remark it in the documentation.

Comment: This feature is well-documented for `find` operations (see [API docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find) and [guide](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)), but not for `update`. From [`update` API docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update) it seems that `callback` is an required parameter, but it's not.