# Mongoose: can't update in save callback

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've this mongoose Schema:

```
var UrlSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   description: String
});
```

Then, I create a model istance:

```
var newUrl = new Url({
  "description": "test"
});

newUrl.save(function (err, doc) {

  if (err) console.log(err);
  else{
      Url.update({_id: doc._id},{description: "a"});
    }
});
```

But any update performed... Why?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongoose update without callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613890/mongoose-update-without-callback)

Comment: This worked fine when I tried it.

Comment: @jibsales, your edit fixed the code, making the question meaningless. =)

Comment: Thanks... I'll put that edit in my answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a callback to the update method or call `#exec()` to perform the update:

```
var newUrl = new Url({
  "description": "test"
});

newUrl.save(function (err, doc) {

  if (err) console.log(err);
  else{

    Url.update({_id: doc._id},{description: "a"}, function (err, numAffected) {
        // numAffected should be 1
    });

    // --OR--
    Url.update({_id: doc._id},{description: "a"}).exec();

  }
});
```

Just FYI: I personally stay away from `update` because it bypasses defaults, setters, middleware, validation, etc which is the main reason to use an ODM like mongoose anyway. I only use `update` when dealing with private data (no user input) and auto incrementing values. I would rewrite as this:

```
var newUrl = new URL({
  "description": "test"
});

newUrl.save(function(err, doc, numAffected) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else {
    doc.set('description', 'a');
    doc.save();
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually, according to [the docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save), the `save` callback takes _three_ arguments: err, doc, numberAffected.

Comment: Wow, I've been using mongoose since 1.x and I've never caught that... RTFM I guess. Updating the post...