# Can't access details of mongoose find() result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using Node/Express with MongoDB, I'm trying to find if there exists an object with a specific field name.

I think the database connection itself is OK because I can add things into the database just fine (confirmed by running the app then checking via mongo shell)

The following code is supposed to increment field `student` of `Class` by 1 and proceed to the next page `/nextpage` if I get a hit.

```
exports.join = function(req,res,next){
 Class.find(({code:{$in: [req.body.roomNumber]}}), function(err, out){
  if(err){res.redirect('/'); next(err);}
  else{
   console.log(out);                 // returns the whole object from db. 
                                     // for no match, I get "[]"
   console.log(req.body.formEntry);  // returns the entered form value OK
   console.log(out.roomNumber);      // always returns "undefined"; why?
   if(out != null) {                 // always passes
    console.log('adding 1 to students');
    Class.update({code:req.body.formEntry}, {$inc:{'students':1}}); // also didn't work
    res.redirect('/nextpage');
   }else{
   console.log('class not found');
   }
  }
 };
}
```

I have tried checking things like `out.params.roomNumber` (get undefined), or `out.next()` (thinking it was a query) but I'm rather confused by the output of `console.log(out.roomNumber)` (ALWAYS undefined) considering the fact that `console.log(out)` gives me the object I want with all its fields intact. I read a similar question but the problem there was on asynchronosity and as this whole thing is in a callback I think perhaps that's not the case.

Comment: You're never executing your update query.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613890/mongoose-update-without-callback/14614070#14614070) for more info.

Comment: Ah, that's another detail I must've overlooked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find` returns an array of results, so `out` is an array.

If every class has a unique room number, using `findOne` makes more sense:

```
Class.findOne({ code : req.body.roomNumber }, function(err, out) {
  // `out` is now a single result, provided there was a match
  ...
});
```

Also, using `$in` to match against a single room number is a bit superfluous, so I left it out of the query (similarly to the query you use for `update`).

As an aside, you shouldn't mix `res.redirect()` and `next()` together (because sending a redirect ends the request, but `next` passes it to other handlers, which will trigger errors in Express). I would suggest using this:

```
if (err) {
  return res.redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: findOne worked perfectly, thanks. EDIT: and redirect+next issues noted.