# Omit callback in javascript function [Mongoose]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I would like to be able to do a one-liner without a callback function to easily update a document asynchronously.
For example,

```
...
{
    ErrorLog.update({}, {$set: {data:data}, function(err) {

    });
    // continue to do stuff here;
}
```

Of course, I can shrink the statement so that it becomes a one-liner, but then there will be an unused callback dangling uglily.

Will it be possible to write something like

```
...
{
    ErrorLog.update({}, {$set: {data:data}, null);
    // continue to do stuff here;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mongoose update without callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613890/mongoose-update-without-callback)

This is exactly what I want, I finally searched google using the right keyword!

Comment: Please close as a duplicate in that case. This should be a comment, not an answer.