# Mongo DB set not working

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a user object in my database using mongodb and mongoose.  Here's the schema:

```
const userSchema = new schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    age: Number,
    ticketsPurchased: [{name: String, date: Date, link: String}],
    admin: Boolean,
    billingAddress: String,
    cityResiding: String,
    stateResiding: String,
    creditCard: String,
});
```

Here's my code trying to update it:

```
socket.on("changeUserInfo", function(data){
    console.log("CHANING USER INFO");
    console.log(data);

    User.update({username: data.username}, {
        $set: {
            firstName: data.firstname,
            lastName: data.lastName,
            billingAddress: data.billingAddress,
            creditCard: data.creditCard,
            stateResiding: data.stateResiding
        }
    });

    User.find({username: data.username}, function(err, user){
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else {
            console.log("USER = " + user);
        }
    });
});
```

The data is correct, it outputs correctly but when I output user in the User.find it remains un-updated.

Comment: Does it work with updateOne? See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613890/mongoose-update-without-callback

Comment: Neither of those worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database operations are asynchronous - you need to provide a callback function or wait a Promise to be resolved in order to be sure about the order of operations.

In your case the `find()` method will most likely return the data before the `update()` operation has finished.

Here is how to acheive what you want - display the updated user:

```
User.update(
  { username: data.username },
  {
    $set: {
      firstName: data.firstname,
      lastName: data.lastName,
      billingAddress: data.billingAddress,
      creditCard: data.creditCard,
      stateResiding: data.stateResiding
    }
  }
)
  .exec()
  .then(() => {
    // you can now be sure that the update has already completed
    User.find({ username: data.username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else {
        console.log("USER = " + user);
      }
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // do not forget to handle errors
  });
```

Comment: This works but only updates the value of billingAddress... I'm debugging now @Tsvetan-Ganev

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Use the '{new:true}' of the 'findOneAndUpdate()'. This will send you the data after changes have been made. Hope this helps!

```
    User.findOneAndUpdate({username:data.username},{$set:
    {
     firstName: data.firstname,
      lastName: data.lastName,
      billingAddress: data.billingAddress,
      creditCard: data.creditCard,
      stateResiding: data.stateResiding
    }
    }, {new:true},
    (err,docs)=>{
    //do something here
    }
    )
```