# mongoose "update" doesnt work unless i use ".then"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i've tried to use mongoose to edit instance on my DB, the update and updateOne function don't work for me unless i use then after the function

this code works:

```
Word.findOne({word:req.body.word}).then(function (res) {
    if (res === null) {
        const new_word = new Word({
            word: req.body.word,
            translate:  req.body.translation
        });
        new_word.save();
    }
    else
        res.updateOne({translate: req.body.translation}).then(function () {});
});
```

this code doesn't work:

```
Word.findOne({word:req.body.word}).then(function (res) {
    if (res === null) {
        const new_word = new Word({
            word: req.body.word,
            translate:  req.body.translation
        });
        new_word.save();
    }
    else
        res.updateOne({translate: req.body.translation});
});
```

thank you in advance :)

Comment: mongoose find, update, delete methods return a promise, so you need  then block,  also  save method also return promise, you need to add then block to there also.

Comment: Mongoose queries return promise and promise does not get resolved until you do not use `.then` with it. It will be always in `pending` state.

Comment: but the "save" function works well without "then" after it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose update without callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613890/mongoose-update-without-callback)

Comment: @LiorSwisa : I know this doesn't answer the question but just checking do you really need to do this in two DB calls, when you've an opportunity of doing upsert - that way you will end up in just one DB call !! But for you're actual question please check this as .then() is similar to callback, this should be the answer you might be looking for :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613890/mongoose-update-without-callback

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using `.exec`?

```
res.updateOne({translate: req.body.translation}).exec();
```

Comment: Not the answer. `.exec` is only used to return full fledged promise.