# MongoDB (Mongoose) update element in array of array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm currently building a REST-Api with node.js express and can't figure out how to update / add elements to the scores Array.

Here is one document from my MongoDB collection (how it should look):

[image: field]

My mongoose model:

```js
const challengesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    createdBy:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    mapType:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    time:{
        type:Number,
        required: true
    },
    numberOfMaps:{
        type:String,
        required: true
    },
    maps:{
        type:Array,
        required: true
    },
    pin:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    takenBy:{
        type: Array,
        required: false
    }
})
```

Basically I receive an id, which I can use to do `Challenges.findById({challenge._id})` .
I figured out how to add an object to the `takenBy Array`, like so:

```js
Challenges.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: challenge._id },
  {
    $push: {
      takenBy: user
    }
  }
);
```

How can I add an element (score, like "20") to the scores array in the array 'takenBy' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can push score and calculate the new TotalScore in one go using [filtered positional operator $](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) like this.

```js
router.put("/challenges/:id/:scoreId", async (req, res) => {
  let score = req.body.score;

  try {
    let result = await Challenges.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.params.id,
      {
        $push: { "takenBy.$[inner].scores": score },
        $inc: {
          "takenBy.$[inner].TotalScore": score
        }
      },
      {
        arrayFilters: [{ "inner._id": req.params.scoreId }],
        new: true
      }
    );

    if (!result) return res.status(404);

    res.send(result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }
});
```

**Test**:

Let's have this existing document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e08fe4c0bc1b932e8726a0f"),
    "maps" : [ ],
    "takenBy" : [
        {
            "_id" : "id1",
            "TotalScore" : NumberInt(100),
            "scores" : [
                NumberInt(20),
                NumberInt(60),
                NumberInt(20)
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : "id2",
            "TotalScore" : NumberInt(30),
            "scores" : [
                NumberInt(10),
                NumberInt(20)
            ]
        }
    ],
    "createdBy" : "5dfe0...",
    "mapType" : "World",
    "time" : NumberInt(2),
    "numberOfMaps" : "2",
    "pin" : "9558",
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

If we want to add a score of 50 to then id1, we send a PUT request  (http://..../challenges/5e08fe4c0bc1b932e8726a0f/id1) with this body:

```
{
    "score": 50
}
```

The result will be like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e08fe4c0bc1b932e8726a0f"),
    "maps" : [ ],
    "takenBy" : [
        {
            "_id" : "id1",
            "TotalScore" : NumberInt(150),
            "scores" : [
                NumberInt(20),
                NumberInt(60),
                NumberInt(20),
                NumberInt(50)
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : "id2",
            "TotalScore" : NumberInt(30),
            "scores" : [
                NumberInt(10),
                NumberInt(20)
            ]
        }
    ],
    "createdBy" : "5dfe0...",
    "mapType" : "World",
    "time" : NumberInt(2),
    "numberOfMaps" : "2",
    "pin" : "9558",
    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
}
```

As you see the score is added to the related item array, and it's TotalScore is also incremented by 50 giving the TotalScore 150

Comment: Thanks! Awesome approach! Is there a way I could not just push to the scores array, but can specify the index where to put my new score in that array?

Comment: @user2557097 yes it seems possible, please have a look at the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/#up._S_position)

Comment: thanks, it works! Like this: `$push: { 
            "takenBy.$[inner].scores": {
                $each: [score],
                $position: scorePosition 
                },
            },`

Comment: @user2557097 great:) You did it by yourself. Please reconsider to accept this answer, this is the way how we update in mongoose.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thanks again!  Another problem I can't figure out: 
The premise of my question was that the takenBy array has objects with ids in it. When the user hasn't submitted a score, it does not add a score. Is there a way to create the object in the taken by array with the corresponding score array and TotalScore in one query? 
I could find the field and search for the Object with the id, if it exists, execute your query, if not create a new field. Is there a way to do this in one query?

Comment: @user2557097 do you want to add a new item to the takenBy array with  TotalScore and scores array?

Comment: Exactly. When the document is created the takenBy array is empty. If it is empty or no Object with the submitted Id exists, it should create a new one. It works with the method I described above, but this requires 2 queries. I was wondering if it could be done in one, like your solution above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205071/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-user2557097).

Comment: @user2557097  I answered in the chat, did you check?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the object first:

```
const updateChallenge = async (req,res) => {
    const challenge = await Challenges.findById(id);
    // Then you make duly changes to it with vanilla js:
    // Find which element in the array takenBy to update 
    // with regular js, methods like filter work or hardcode it

    challenge.takenBy[1].push(newElement);

    await challenge.save();
    // DONE! :)
}
```

Of course you can use destructuring if you prefer!

Answer (score 0):

> ...how to update / add elements to the scores Array.

I would first retrieve that array... Push the new value, then update.

Something like:

```
Challenges.findById(challenge._id,(err, db_result) => {
  if(err){
    console.log(err)              // error management
    //...
  }

  if(db_result){

    // Get the takenBy array
    let takenBy = db_result.takenBy

    // Who are we talking about... You need the second _id for that record
    let who_id = user._id

    let targetIndex = null
    let byWho = takenBy.filter((who, index) => {

      let gotYa = who._id === who_id
      if (gotYa){
        targetIndex = index
      }
      return gotYa  // Boolean used as a return for .filter()
    })

    if(byWho.length>0){
      console.log("Got someone... Index: ", targetIndex)
    }else{
      console.log("No one found?")
      return
    }


    // Push the new value using the index where to update.
    takenBy[targetIndex].scores.push(challenge.score)

    Challenges.updateOne({_id:challenge._id},{
        $set: {
          takenBy: takenBy
        }
      }, (err, data) => {
        console.log(data)
      }
    )

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! the Challenges.updateOne does not work. I need to update / add a score in the array, which is in the the takenBy array. So how can I use $set to change e.g. the first object of the takenBy array and update the scores?

Comment: Ho, I missed the fact the `score` array is in the `takenBy` array... I will update my answer. But the concept is the same. It's `get`, `push`, `set`. ;)

Comment: hahem... Maybe you have to target the right `takenBy` element... Do you have the second `id` for it? Hold on a bit more... I'm editing

Comment: Try that... ;) We should be close.

Comment: It finally works! The problem in the end was that the updateOne function only changes the database document, when it has a callback function, like you did in the first line. I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613890/mongoose-update-without-callback). So everything works now, thanks!

Comment: Mind to accept the answer then? I'm happy for you. Enjoy coding!

Comment: Actually with await you should not need a callback function..

Comment: @MattiaRasulo: From my very short experience, Mongo methods are best used with their callbacks. It works well that way. And failed the `await` way... So I admit I I can't fully dismiss your point. but... --- I don't know what and when Mongo methods are returning, in fact.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I'm not an expert in JS, especially regarding async, but I agree. I could wrap it in a try-catch-block and use `return await Challenges. ....`
If I use a callback function, I don't see a reason to use await in this case, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @user2557097 did you check my answer? It is clearer than this answer. Also only one db access, also updates the TotalScore.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I'm testing it right now. It accomplishes the same thing, but it's short and requires only one database query. Both are nice answer, but I might mark yours, but thanks to both of you!

Comment: I agree @SuleymanSah answer is best. you made the right choice. (I upvoted his answer) I will leave my answer there anyway, because I think it is instructive about the process.